# Why is min-width property has preference over max-width?

Tags: css

Here is my code the width of the element is now taking 400px but as both of the properties i have given is contradictory i know one will apply, is there a way that max width to get preference over min width? if not why? i have tried adding min-width property before and after max width both time the same thing is happening. Kindly explain

```
p {     background:red;    
        min-width:400px;
        max-width:200px;
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure why but If you look at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp it says that min-width overides max-width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width):

> max-width overrides width, but min-width overrides max-width

So i think there is **no way** to make `max-width` have higher priority than `min-width`

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#min-max-widths) the value of the `max-width` overrides `width` property, and the `min-width` property value overrides both `max-width` and `width`. See also [explanation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) on the W3Schools.